# Dividing by macro-defined int in C gives weird result

Tags: c

I am wondering why this program doesn't seem to do integer division properly when the denominator is defined in a macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 2
#define B 64
#define C A * B

int main() {
     int addr = 64;
     int idx = addr / C;
     printf("C=%d\n", C);
     printf("%d\n", idx);
     printf("%d\n", addr / 128);
     return 0;
}
```

Output on my computer:

```
C=128
2048
0
```

Expected output:

```
C=128
0
0
```

Comment: Read up on order of operations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic arithmetic.

Comment: Actually, I think he thought the macro would expand C as "128", not as "A * B". As such, this Q/A is informative if you're making that mistake.

Comment: @Almo As such, this question is a duplicate of a good hundred identical questions, one of which appeared in the first page of results when searching for “[c] strange macro”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int idx = addr / C;
```

becomes

```
int idx = addr / A * B; // or 64/2 * 64 == 32*64
```

Answer (score 0):

After macro expansion, you have

```
addr / 2 * 64
```

Due to operator precendence that's

```
32 * 64
```

You could add parentheses to your macro

```
#define C (A * B)
```